# Can an external function works in derived contract in solidity?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

I made a function with visibility **external** in a contract A but When I tried to access through a derived contract B, it's giving an error.

**`Code:`**

```
contract A{

      function f1() pure public  returns(uint) { 
       return 1;
    }

      function f2() pure private returns(uint) { 
       return 2;
    } 
     
    function f3() pure internal returns(uint){   
        return 3;
    }

    function f4() pure external returns(uint){ 
        return 4;
    }
}

contract B is A{ 
   
     uint bx = f3();  
}
```

[image: Error Image]

If the answer is yes, state the reason. And then why it's  working in contract C. Is it because it's not a derived contract?. State it's reason too.

[image: Contract C image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solidity documentation gives a spot on answer for your question, leaving me not much to explain. See [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/contracts.html#function-visibility) for other visibilities

Solidity knows two kinds of function calls: external ones that do create an actual EVM message call and internal ones that do not. Furthermore, internal functions can be made inaccessible to derived contracts. This gives rise to four types of visibility for functions.

> External functions are part of the contract interface, which means they can be called from other contracts and via transactions. An external function f cannot be called internally (i.e. f() does not work, but this.f() works).